# Applescript - open Microsoft Word 2011 document as read only

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

Using Applescript, I want to open a Microsoft Word Document in read only mode.

The Word Applescript Dictionary indicates that I should be able to do this, but it doesn't appear to work. Using the following, the document opens in read/write mode:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open file "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:test.docx" with read only
end tell
```

I can open a document in read only mode with the following Visual Basic (VB):

```
Sub Test()
    Documents.Open fileName:="Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:test.docx", ReadOnly:=True
End Sub
```

I would just use a VB script, but the ability to call VB from Applescript has been removed in Word 2011 ("do Visual Basic" is no longer in the dictionary. You can call a predefined macro, but I don't think you can pass variables to it, so a macro would not work in my situation).

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "open file name", instead of just "open file" resolved the issue.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open file name "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:test.doc" with read only
end tell
```